# How to quickly show policies of all docker containers

Tags: docker

Is there a way to quickly show policies of all running docker containers?

For instance, I'm trying to find a way to list all currently running  containers that do not have a restart policy set or to list all containers that have RestartPolicy set to "always".

I know I can use docker inspect  to see the RestartPolicy of individual containers, but doing this one by one is a bit tedious.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make the command line run `docker inspect` on each container for you by combining `docker ps -aq` and `xargs`, and some [`docker inspect` template magic](http://container-solutions.com/docker-inspect-template-magic/) lets you see only the names of the containers with `--restart=always` like so:

```
docker ps -aq | xargs docker inspect -f \
    '{{if eq .HostConfig.RestartPolicy.Name "always"}}{{.Name}}{{end}}'
```

or, for the containers with no restart policy:

```
docker ps -aq | xargs docker inspect -f \
    '{{if eq .HostConfig.RestartPolicy.Name ""}}{{.Name}}{{end}}'
```